# How can I emit from component and listen from another one?

Tags: vue.js

I have in `Layout.vue` to components one `TheSidebar` second `TheHeader`, there is a button in `TheHeader` to open the sidebar in `TheSidebar`component.

I need to when I click the button in header open the sidebar:

My try:

in `TheHeader`:

```
methods: {
  openSidebar() {
    this.$root.$emit("open-sidebar");
  },
},
```

in `TheSidebar`

```
data() {
  return {
    sidebarOpen: false,
  };
},
mounted() {
  this.$root.$on("open-sidebar", (this.sidebarOpen = true));
},
```

I'm using  VUE 3 so I got this error in console: `TypeError: this.$root.$on is not a function` so How can communicate ?

Comment: Yes, emit and listen are great... but you can also try to look into doing this via a store. Personally I like Vuex, but I hear Pinia is getting the preferred tag. A store would keep track of the open/close status of your sidebar, and would be accessible at any time for any other component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use something like [tiny emitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-emitter) it works fine and doesn't care about parent child relationship

```
var emitter = require('tiny-emitter/instance');
 
emitter.on('open-sidebar', ({isOpen}) => {
 //
});
 
emitter.emit('open-sidebar', {isOpen : true} );
```

Comment: thank you so much it's an amazing tool! my small question how can I make it globally like any component  I need to use, cuz now I just directly import it in "TheHeader"!

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass props to a direct child component, and

you can only emit an event to a direct parent. But

you can [provide and eject](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html) from anywhere to anywhere

Comment: JS has custom events, surely this can be implemented in Vue.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Answer (score 1):

Per another answer, provide and eject may be your best bet in Vue 3, but I created a simple example of how to implement with props/events.  Built with Vue 2 as I haven't worked with 3 yet, but should be usable in Vue 3 as well.

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h4>Parent</h4>
        <hr>
        <child-one @show-child-two-event="handleShowChildTwoEvent" />
        <hr>
        <child-two v-if="showChildTwo" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import ChildOne from './ChildOne.vue'
  import ChildTwo from './ChildTwo.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      ChildOne,
      ChildTwo
    },
    data() {
      return {
        showChildTwo: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      handleShowChildTwoEvent() {
        this.showChildTwo = true;
      }
    }

  }
</script>
```

ChildOne.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child-one">
    <h4>Child One</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="showChildTwo">Show Child Two</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      showChildTwo() {
        this.$emit('show-child-two-event');
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

ChildTwo.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child-two">
    <h4>Child Two</h4>
  </div>
</template>
```